# how to delete the text on number 1 and2

Tags: python

hi all I'm a beginner in coding so I very need your help
so I need an answer
can I delete text in row number 1,2and3?

```
print ("hello")
print ("wellcome to this cmd ")
print ("i wish you happy")
input("Press Enter to continue...")
print ("wellcome")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... kind off. You can store each word or sentence in a variable of your choice like this

```
hello = 'hello'
welcomeToThis = 'your text'
happy = 'which you were happy'
```

And right before you implement you print statement you can make each variable blank like this:
hello = ''
Does this solve you problem?

```
welcome = ''
input("Press Enter to continue...")
print(welcome)
```

Other wise you can just delete the code?